# Limit google autofill location to a particular city

Tags: javascript, html, api, autofill

I am using google's autofill address API to fill locations but what I want is after filling the city, textbox of address should only show suggestions of addresses in that city not all addresses. Below is the html code for  city and address

```
 <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Base City</label>
<div class="col-md-3">
<input type="text" id="loca" name="City" class="form-control"  >
</div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Base Location</label>
<div class="col-md-3">
<input type="text" id="locb" name="Location" class="form-control"  >
</div>
</div>
```

Script for google api address suggestions

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en-AU"></script>
    <script>
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#loc")[0], {});

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log(place.address_components);
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, currently, google API doesn't support bound by city name. Therefore, you either should use longitude and latitude to set bounds or the area around the city you chose (f.e. obj.geometry.viewport).

Viewpoint will return the streets not only from the city you chose but also from the cities around, for example, if you choose New York city  it will return the results from the city of New York and from Brooklyn. So in my suggested code autocomplete will suggest you results from both neighboring cities, but the code later will parse user's chose and make sure the cities match, if the cities doesn't match it will set both fields to empty string.

Also the way I wrote my code is that autocomplete on the second field will be turned on only after choice in the first field is made. The better way is to make second field appear only first field is chose, but it is something you should do on your own. In addition, there is potential bug which is related to how autocomplete stores previously chosen values, if you want your code 100% functioning, you might wanna clear cash of autocomplete functionality or the fields itself instead of  $("#locb").val('');

```js
var autocompleteA = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#loca")[0], { types: ['(cities)'] });
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteA, 'place_changed', function () {
            var placeA = autocompleteA.getPlace();
            var boundsByViewport = autocompleteA.getPlace().geometry.viewport;
            var autocompleteB = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#locb")[0], {
                bounds: boundsByViewport,
                types: ['address']
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteB, 'place_changed', function () {
                var placeB = autocompleteB.getPlace();
                var match = false;
                for (var i = 0; i < placeB.address_components.length; i++) {
                    if ((placeA.address_components[0]).long_name === (placeB.address_components[i].long_name)) {
                        { //"The city names matched"
                            //do what you need with it
                            alert("City is the same");
                            match = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!match) {       //warn that it is not the right adress
                    alert("The city names didn't match.");
                  
                    //clear value of the Location field
                    $("#loca").val('');
                    $("#locb").val('');
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en-AU"></script>

<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Base City</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" id="loca" name="City" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Base Location</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" id="locb" name="Location" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```